# How is a sigma algebra of a r.v. different from a sigma algebra of a set of i.i.d r.v.s?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Towards random walk. Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be independent and identically distributed.
Let $S_n=S_0+X_1+...+X_n$, where $S_0$ is a constant.
Let $F_n=\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$ for $n\geq1$.

I am having trouble understanding what $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$ is. As I understand, because $X_1,X_2,...$ are i.i.d., their preimages in sample space should be the same.

1. If we are creating sigma algebra from there, isn't $\sigma(X_1)$ and $\sigma(X_2)$ equal?
2. Isn't $\sigma(X_1)$ also equal to $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$?

Comment: Actually, $\sigma (X_1)$ and $\sigma (X_2)$ cannot be equal except in the trivial case where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma(X_1)$ is the family of sets $X_1\in A$ for $A$ a measurable set.

So you are saying $X_1\in A$ and $X_2\in A$ are the same? No. $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution, so $X_1\in A$ and $X_2\in A$ have equal probabilities, but they are not the same, as $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$ have equal lengths but are not the same. Moreover, $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$, so $\mathbb P(X_1\in A,X_2\in A)=\mathbb P(X_1\in A)\mathbb P(X_2\in A)=\mathbb P(X_1\in A)^2$. If we had that $X_1\in A$ and $X_2\in A$ were the same, then we would have $\mathbb P(X_1\in A,X_2\in A)=\mathbb P(X_1\in A)$, hence $\mathbb P(X_1\in A)=\mathbb P(X_1\in A)^2$, or equivalently $\mathbb P(X_1\in A)\in\{0,1\}$. So $X_1\in A$ and $X_2\in A$ are never the same when they are not trivial (that is either negligible or certain).

The fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent mean that the knowledge of having $X_1\in A$ should have no impact on the distribution of $X_2$. Yet if $X_1\in A$ and $X_2\in A$ were the same, then having $X_1\in A$ would imply $X_2\in A$, which impacts its distribution if its original distribution was not initially with total mass in $A$.

To answer your second question: $\sigma(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\sigma(X_1),\cdots,\sigma(X_n)$. We can show that a real-valud random variable $Y$ is $\sigma(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$-measurable iff $Y=f(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ almost surely for some measurable map $f$. And $Y$ is $\sigma(X_1)$-measurable iff $Y=g(X_1)$ for some measurable map $g$. So $X_1+X_2$ is $\sigma(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$-measurable but not $\sigma(X_1)$-measurable, hence those two $\sigma$-algebras are not the same.